# removing specific element from vector's range

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I want to delete element if its value is matching the string "empty", so iterate thorough loop but its not working that way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::vector<std::string> myvector;

  myvector.push_back("value");
  myvector.push_back("value");
  myvector.push_back("empty");
  myvector.push_back("value");
  myvector.push_back("value");
  myvector.push_back("empty");
  myvector.push_back("empty");

  int index = 0;
  for(string input: myvector){
    if(input == "empty")
        myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+index,myvector.begin()+index);
    index++;
  }

  for(string input: myvector){
    cout << input << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but we can see that nothing is deleted?
ouput :

```
value
value
empty
value
value
empty
empty
```

Looking for something like below but doesn't exists

```
myvector.erase(myvector.begin(),myvector.end(),"empty");
```

so how to achieve it in less complexity?

Comment: Look at [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use std::remove_if like this:

```
myvector.erase(std::remove_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](const std::string& string){ return (string == "empty"); }), myvector.end());
```

Comment: No need to use `std::remove_if` and a lambda here, why not simply use `std::remove` with the value `"empty"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    std::vector<std::string> myvector;
    myvector.push_back("value");
    myvector.push_back("value");
    myvector.push_back("empty");
    myvector.push_back("value");
    myvector.push_back("value");
    myvector.push_back("empty");
    myvector.push_back("empty");
    auto it = std::remove_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
    [](const std::string& s)
    { 
        return (s== "empty"); 
    });
    myvector.erase(it, myvector.end());
```

1. use `remove_if` to put all found `"empty"` at the end of `vector`.
2. use returned `iterator` to erase them.